# Gridview Footer total using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, gridview

I was used this Code for sum the Column value s

```
int total = 0;
protected void gvEmp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount"));
}
if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
Label lblamount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
lblamount.Text = total.ToString();
}
}
```

I'have more data's in my database . so i have decided to use Linq Query  which is below

```
GridView1.Columns[8].FooterText = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   select row.Field<int>("amount")).Sum().ToString();
```

but I have Paging in my Grid , Page size is 50 so i have to sum the 1 st page total at first  If i Click to 2nd Page then  i have to show the 2nd page total. how to achieve that ?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/986566.aspx Check the last reply. With this You should figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
GridView1.Columns[8].FooterText = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   select row.Field<int>("amount")).Skip(GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize).Take(GridView1.PageSize).Sum().ToString();
```